# How to remove footer and header while creating a pandas dataframe by loading an excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I have loaded an excel file using pd.read_excel(). The dataframe has header data in the top 6 rows and footer data from the 213th row till the last row(232th). I need to remove the header and footer and get a new database. How can I do this using bollean masking?

Comment: the [read excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) option has  ```skprows``` and a ```skipfooter``` parameters, that allow u specify positions u want to remove from the top and bottom respectively

Comment: Please convert your input (Excel) file to CSV version and add top / trailing lines from it (+ a few data rows), **as text** (not an image). The reason, especially for top rows, is that they may indicate whether to skip some of them or read as the MultiIndex on columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the following code:

```
df=df[(df.index>6)&(df.index<213)]
df.index-=7
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the input file contains something like:

```
  The title of the whole data set

=============================================
Date,Amount,Aaaa,Aaaa,Bbbb,Bbbb
 , ,Start,Stop,Start,Stop
=============================================
2012-01-01,120.5,10,20,21,28
2012-01-02,130.9,12,24,25,30
2012-01-03,140.0,13,28,29,36
2012-01-04,150.7,15,32,31,44
2012-01-05,160.1,19,36,36,70
=============================================
Summary row - to be skipped
=============================================
```

Details:

- Row 0 thru 2 (zero-based numbers) - skip entirely.
- Row 3 and 4 - actual column titles (MultiIndex).
- Row 5 - skip.
- Data rows (in my example 5).
- Last 3 rows - footer, to be skipped.

Note also that the second title row contains spaces as 2 initial
names. Otherwise *read_csv* assigns default names, composed of *Unnamed:*
+ a number. It is better to avoid them.

To read this content, you can call:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', skiprows=[0, 1, 2, 5],
    header=[0, 1], skipfooter=3, engine='python')
```

How these parameters are interpreted:

- `skiprows` - skip rows with these indices.
- `header` - from these lines read column names.
- `skipfooter` - skip 3 last lines.
- `engine` - you must specify *python*, otherwise *read_csv* attempts
  to usethe default *c* engine, which dous not support *skipfooter*,
  so it switches to *python* engine, issuing a warning.

Note that line numbers passed as *header* indicate lines **after** *skiprows* (in the original input file their row indices are actually *3* and *4*).

The result is:

```
         Date Amount  Aaaa       Bbbb     
                     Start Stop Start Stop
0  2012-01-01  120.5    10   20    21   28
1  2012-01-02  130.9    12   24    25   30
2  2012-01-03  140.0    13   28    29   36
3  2012-01-04  150.7    15   32    31   44
4  2012-01-05  160.1    19   36    36   70
```

i.e. a MultiIndex on columns (2 levels), 5 data rows and no source footer.

## Edit

Other option is to skip **entirely** 6 initial lines.
In this case:

- pass `skiprows=6` to skip 6 initial lines,
- pass `header=None` to block reading of the first line as the
  column names row, then column names will be set as consecutive numbers
  stating from *0*,
- or pass `names` parameter with column names to be used (but this time
  only "plain" index on columns can be specified).